# How to pass a form value to another view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

How to get a form value form one view to another.
for example i would like to get the 'web_input' value from  InputWebView() and pass it into DisplayWebView()

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {{ form.web_input }}
    <input type="submit">
</form/>

def InputWebView(requests)
    form = WebInputForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('add_web', web_url=request.POST['web_input'])



def DisplayWebView(request, web_url):
    url = web_url
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions) to pass data from one view to another. In `InputWebView`:

```
def InputWebView(requests)
    form = WebInputForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['web_input'] = request.POST['web_input']
            return redirect('add_web')
```

In `DisplayWebView`:

```
def DisplayWebView(request):
    url = request.session.get('web_input')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution, however i'm getting  a self is not defined.

Comment: @lolz oops, remove `self` and change to `request.session['web_input'] = request.POST['web_input']`.